# Mapping of a region under $\cosh(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the image of the region $$z = re^{i\theta} : r>2 \text{ and } \pi/4 < \theta < \pi/3$$ under $w = \cosh(z)$.

The way I attempted to solve the problem is by mapping the lines bordering the region onto the W plane and then finding the region between the mapped borders. I used the rectangular form of $z = x + iy$, where $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$. The real part (u) of w: $$ Re(\cosh(z)) = \cosh(x)\cos(y)$$ and the imaginary part (v) of w:$$ Im(\cosh(z)) = \sinh(x)\sin(y)$$

For vertical/horizontal lines it is easy to eliminate $x,y$ from the equations and have a relation between $u$ and $v$, but in this case, I couldn't manage to eliminate both $x$ and $y$. As a last resort, I plotted the transformation, and it looks something like this (the blue one is for the line corresponding to $\theta = \pi/3$ in the z when transformed to the w plane plane and orange one likewise for $\pi/4$)  [image: plot]

The region would then be the space between those two plots when going from orange one to blue one in anti-clockwise direction.

Is there a better to way to solve the problem? Thank you.

Comment: $\pi/2 < \theta < \pi/4$ ? That would be an empty region.

Comment: Edited, Its meant to be $\pi/4 < \theta < \pi/3$

Comment: A user helped you to write the set notation for your region. Why did you undo those changes?

Comment: It was not showing correctly after the edit @jjagmath

Answer (score 0):

In order to get an impression with variing outer radius rmax, make a plot eg in Mathematica

```
     Manipulate[Show[
       {ParametricPlot[
  ReIm[Cosh[{2 } E^(I \[Phi])]], {\[Phi], \[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/3}, 
  PlotStyle -> Green],
 ParametricPlot[ReIm[Cosh[ r E^(I \[Pi]/3)]], {r, 2, rmax}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red],
  ParametricPlot[
  ReIm[Cosh[ rmax E^(I \[Phi])]], {\[Phi], \[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/3}, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue],
 ParametricPlot[ReIm[Cosh[ r E^(I \[Pi]/4)]], {r, 2, rmax}, 
  PlotStyle -> Yellow]},
         ImageSize -> 200, PlotRange -> All], {rmax, 2, 12}]
```

For small rmax

[image: Complex Map 1]

and larger rmax

[image: complex map 2]